# Ordenar datos en una vista laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo una consulta, resulta que en mi controlador de Eventos recibo todos los eventos de un profesor pero me gustaria ordenarlos por fecha

Este es el index de mi controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
{   
    $profesor = Profesor::find(auth('profesor')->user()->id);
    $mis_eventos = $profesor->eventos->all();
    return view('eventos.index')->with('mis_eventos',$mis_eventos)->with('profesor',$profesor)->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```

En que parte debo colocar el order by ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cuando defines `$profesor`, puedes hacer eager loading de sus eventos directamente, sin necesidad de definir una variable adicional:

```
$profesor = Profesor::find(...)->with('eventos')->get();
```

Puedes precargar el orden definiéndolo en la relación, en tu modelo:

```
public function eventos()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Evento::class)->orderBy('fecha');
}
```

Comment: Gracias, intente con ->with('eventos') pero no supe mostrar los valosres en la vista, con lo de la relacion lo solucione.

Answer (score -1):

Intenta realizando lo siguiente en tu código:

```
$mis_eventos = $profesor->eventos->orderBy('campo_de_fecha')->all();
```